# Is there a Python module to handle csv files with sections?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm seeing more and more csv files containing multiple sections, each containing their own table. For instance this file from [10XGenomics](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/using/multi#examples):

```
[gene-expression]
reference,/path/to/transcriptome

[libraries]
fastq_id,fastqs,feature_types
gex1,/path/to/fastqs,Gene Expression
mux1,/path/to/fastqs,Multiplexing Capture

[samples]
sample_id,cmo_ids
sample1,CMO301
sample2,CMO303
```

Sometimes the section headers are even embedded in their own row, e.g.

```
[gene-expression],,
reference,/path/to/transcriptome,
[libraries],,
fastq_id,fastqs,feature_types
gex1,/path/to/fastqs,Gene Expression
mux1,/path/to/fastqs,Multiplexing Capture
[samples],,
sample_id,cmo_ids,
sample1,CMO301,
sample2,CMO303,
```

Is there a Python module to handle this kind of sectioning directly? I couldn't find how to do it with Pandas or the `csv` module. E.g. from both examples above I would expect to get a dictionary with one item per section, and then a list of lists for each section.

Some sections have headers, it would be nice if this could be handled too, e.g. similarly to `csv.DictReader`.

Although it's not particularly hard to write a solution that can parse this particular example, producing something that works in the general case is much harder, e.g. parsing a simple csv file is easily done with `split` and yet the `csv` module is 400+ lines of Python, and many more lines of C, so what I'm really looking for here is a module to handle this problem in general.

PS: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701696/is-there-a-python-package-to-parse-readable-data-files-with-sections) is related but the answers do not address the point about the csv parser unfortunately

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a csv file with multiple data sections into an addressable structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031684/read-a-csv-file-with-multiple-data-sections-into-an-addressable-structure)

Comment: How should look like your targeted csv (*based on the two examples*) ? Can you add it to your question ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've clarified my question a little bit. In short I'm not looking for code to handle this particular example but more like a general solution that can process csv files with sections.

Comment: The problem is that this kind of file is still not common enough for someone to develop a specific library. Or the specs are not stable enough. Honestly, I sometimes had to face such *poorly formatted files*, and everytime I chose to build *by hand* a custom pre-processor to split the file in nicely formatted sections. And I never regretted not to try to build a generic tool, because each time I found enough differences for the previous tool to be useless. If really you have a serious usage, and can write precise specs, then it may be worth it...

Comment: ... If you choose to go that way, feel free to come back here if you need any help to build your tools. But IMHO the hard part will be to write down a specification that will be able to accept all of your use cases and at the same time will be *simple* enough to justify a library.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I was afraid of... thanks for you input anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module to read your file:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import io
import pandas as pd

cfg = ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
cfg.optionxform = str
cfg.read('data.csv')

dfs = {}
for section in cfg.sections():
    buf = io.StringIO()
    buf.writelines('\n'.join(row.rstrip(',') for row in cfg[section]))
    buf.seek(0)
    dfs[section] = pd.read_csv(buf)
```

Output:

```
>>> dfs['gene-expression']
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [reference, /path/to/transcriptome]
Index: []

>>> dfs['libraries']
  fastq_id           fastqs         feature_types
0     gex1  /path/to/fastqs       Gene Expression
1     mux1  /path/to/fastqs  Multiplexing Capture

>>> dfs['samples']
  sample_id cmo_ids
0   sample1  CMO301
1   sample2  CMO303
```

Now you can also just want to extract a section:

```
cfg = ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
cfg.optionxform = str
cfg.read('data.csv')

def read_data(section):
    buf = io.StringIO()
    buf.writelines('\n'.join(row.rstrip(',') for row in cfg[section]))
    buf.seek(0)
    return pd.read_csv(buf)

df = read_data('samples')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  sample_id cmo_ids
0   sample1  CMO301
1   sample2  CMO303
```

Comment: I really thought that would work, but it turns out `configparser` converts all the data to lower case (as can be seen in the example you provided actually), ughhh...

Comment: @Aratz. Don't worry about that ;-). I updated my answer. Just add `cfg.optionxform = str`.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly easy to use `itertools.groupby()` to handle parsing files with sections like this for the `csv` standard library module:

```
import csv
import io
import itertools

s = """\
[gene-expression]
reference,/path/to/transcriptome

[libraries]
fastq_id,fastqs,feature_types
gex1,/path/to/fastqs,Gene Expression
mux1,/path/to/fastqs,Multiplexing Capture

[samples]
sample_id,cmo_ids
sample1,CMO301
sample2,CMO303
"""

def is_header(l):
    return l.strip().startswith("[") and l.strip().endswith("]")

f = io.StringIO(s)
grouped = itertools.groupby(f, is_header)

try: 
    while True:
        _, header = next(grouped)
        header = list(csv.reader(header))[-1][0]
        _, section = next(grouped)
        section = list(csv.reader(section))

        print(header)
        print(section)
        
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

If you have Python 3.10 or higher, you can combine `itertools.groupby()` with `itertools.pairwise()` which would make this even simpler:

```
s = """\
[gene-expression]
reference,/path/to/transcriptome

[libraries]
fastq_id,fastqs,feature_types
gex1,/path/to/fastqs,Gene Expression
mux1,/path/to/fastqs,Multiplexing Capture

[samples]
sample_id,cmo_ids
sample1,CMO301
sample2,CMO303
"""

import csv
import io
import itertools

f = io.StringIO(s)

def is_header(l):
    return l.strip().startswith("[") and l.strip().endswith("]")
    
grouped = itertools.groupby(f, is_header)
paired = itertools.pairwise(list(g) for k, g in grouped)

data = {header[-1].strip("[]\n"): list(csv.reader(section)) for header, section in paired}
print(data)
```

Comment: I like this because it is "safest" in the handling of the CSV columns (quoted, unquoted etc.). Unfortunately many biotech companies insist on using invalid CSV in preference to some common structured data format, and there is no predicting what the lab operators may type into their forms.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) to handle *both formats* :

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = (pd.read_fwf("input.txt", header=None, names=["data"])
        .assign(section=lambda x: x["data"].str.extract("\[(.*)\]").ffill())
)

d_dfs = { # type hint: Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]
    k: (g.iloc[1:,0].str.split(",", expand=True)
           .pipe(lambda df_: 
              df_.rename(columns=df_.iloc[0])
                 .drop(df_.index[0])))
    for k, g in df.groupby('section')
}
```

Output :

```
>>> print(d_dfs["libraries"])

  fastq_id           fastqs         feature_types
4     gex1  /path/to/fastqs       Gene Expression
5     mux1  /path/to/fastqs  Multiplexing Capture

>>> print(d_dfs["samples"])

  sample_id cmo_ids
8   sample1  CMO301
9   sample2  CMO303
```